# map draw route in markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using map and drawing markers on it initially in initMap().
here is my code:

```
var makerLocationList = [
            {lat: 19.99335320785088, lng: 73.68118286132812,title:"first marker"},
            {lat: 19.98593250903381, lng: 73.7124252319336,title:"second marker"},
            {lat: 19.997454, lng: 73.789803,title:"third marker"}
        ];

function initMap() {
        var haightAshbury = {lat: 19.997454, lng: 73.789803};

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 12,
          center: haightAshbury,
         // mapTypeId: 'terrain'
        });
        for(i=0;i<makerLocationList.length;i++){
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(makerLocationList[i]["lat"], makerLocationList[i]["lng"]),
                map: map,
                title: makerLocationList[i]["title"]
            });
        }
}
```

It draws markers perfectly as loop travel but I want to join newly created marker with the last on.

So that it works like create first marker then create second and draw route and connect first with second then create third maker and join second with third and so on.

Comment: have you looked into the google maps route API?

Comment: yes i got details about route between source and destination but not by location wise as i draw maker

Comment: not sure I understand what routes you say you have, as you are not using any of the route API in your code

Comment: i am placing makers and i want them to  connect so it will create route

Comment: yes, that's where you want to use the google maps directions API (sorry, wasn't route API) - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions